# Detecting TouchableWithoutFeedback long press release

Tags: ios, react-native

How do I detect when a longPress is released (not by dragging away). `onPressOut` does say when it's released but it also triggers when finger is dragged away from the button.

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
    onLongPress={() => this.onLongPress()}
    onPressOut={() => this.onCancel()}
    onPressIn={() => this.onHover()}
    onPress={() => this.onPress()}
  >
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a massive (bigger than the screen) pressRetentionOffset? This should prevent the touch from cancelling unless you release.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
    ...
    pressRetentionOffset={{ top: 1000, left: 1000, bottom: 1000, right: 1000 }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should do that?

> Cancel-ability- when making an action, the user should be able to abort it mid-touch by dragging their finger away

from Facebook's Best Practices section:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#best-practices

If you still need to do it, you may need to implement a custom touchable using `View.props.onResponderMove` and `View.props.onResponderRelease`

See docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html#responder-lifecycle

Comment: Thats exactly why I want to do that. The user cannot cancel the longpress by dragging their finger away.